# PHP looping code with sleep

Tags: php

So I'm sort of noob at this but I need to ask this, is there a way in PHP to have a piece of code be exacuted x amount of times and then sleep and redo itself x amount of times?

Comment: See [`sleep()`](http://us1.php.net/sleep)

Comment: a for loop inside a for loop...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be up to task:

```
    for($i=0;$i<$redoCount;$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<$x;$j++){
            //piece of code
        }
        sleep($secondToSleep);
    }
```